# Edit Tags Feature Broken - Can't Save

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, inline-tag-editor

When I click the Edit Tags link I'm able to edit the tags as I would normally, but there's no save button or link. I'm seeing this on stackoverflow.com <strike>and here on meta as well</strike>. The Save Tag Edits button is now back here but still MIA on SO.

Comment: Yeah, just started for me, too. You can still do a normal edit and change the tags there.

Comment: Maybe there's in the process of rolling out the fix, and they did meta first.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah that's how I'm getting around it, but I wanted to report it anyway

Comment: Of course, I was about to report it myself but I checked [meta.se] and here first.

Comment: @Barmar Seems to be working again on SO

Comment: This is the SO equivalent of a [First World Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_World_problem) :)

Comment: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7901894#7901894

Comment: We have a two step rollout (three if you count teams) where we first build out MSO and MSE then separately build out the rest of the network.  This gives us a window to do sanity checks on bigger releases.  That's why you first saw the issue disappear here, and 5 minutes later on the main site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is fixed.

The tag editor was annotated `<div class="form-item p0">`, where `.form-item` gave the element padding, and `.p0` took it away, so someone doing a cleanup pass stripped both out.

Unfortunately the inline tag editor inserts its button with a `form.find('div.form-item').insertAfter(saveButton)`, so the save button was inserted after nothing.

The two key problems are:

1. The tag editor reusable component lacked clearly defined integration points.
2. We made changes to a reusable component without testing all the contexts in which it was used.

For #1, I've annotated the component and am now selecting it with a JavaScript only class (i.e., one that starts with `.js-` as a hint for future developers.  For #2, we just need to exercise stronger discipline when touching this type of component, ensuring extensive regression tests are factored into the test plan.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick fix.

Comment: Okay, when will you start [handling the suggested edits review queue](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7901896#7901896)?  ;)

Comment: @rene [Be careful what you wish for.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBOqi.jpg)

Comment: Standing by with the canned “robo-reviewer” review ban message.